How should the Singleton Room Database and Opening and Closing procedures be?
I use multiple room databases in my application. I want to open it in the necessary activities and then close it in the on destroy method, but sometimes there may be delays. I need to make better improvements. Could you please make corrections to this simple example and create a documentation?
Database Class
@Database(entities = {UserFood.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class UserFoodDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserFoodDao daoAccess();

    public static volatile UserFoodDatabase userFoodDatabase;

    public static UserFoodDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (userFoodDatabase == null) {
            synchronized (UserFoodDatabase.class) {
                if (userFoodDatabase == null) {
                    userFoodDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    UserFoodDatabase.class, USER_FOODS_DB_NAME)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return userFoodDatabase;
    }
}


Singleton Helper Class
public class AppDatabaseHelper {
    private static volatile UserFoodDatabase userFoodDatabase;

    public static UserFoodDatabase getUserFoodDatabase(Context context) {
        if (userFoodDatabase == null) {
            userFoodDatabase = UserFoodDatabase.getDatabase(context);
        }
        return userFoodDatabase;
    }

    public static void closeUserFoodDatabase() {
        if (userFoodDatabase != null) {
            if (userFoodDatabase.isOpen()) {
                userFoodDatabase.close();
            }
            if (userFoodDatabase != null) {
                userFoodDatabase = null;
            }
        }
    }
  }


Some Activity
public class FoodListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        executor.execute(() -> {
            UserFoodDao userFoodDao = AppDatabaseHelper.getUserFoodDatabase(FoodListActivity.this).daoAccess();
            handler.post(this::dataLoadMethod);
            executor.shutdown();
        });
}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("LIFECYCLE", "onDestroy");
        new Thread(() -> {
            AppDatabaseHelper.closeUserFoodDatabase();
        }).start();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
  }


I created the singleton helper class, but I can't be sure if it is correct. Also, how are open, close and re-open operations performed in the room database?

Why is the question tagged with [tag:kotlin] when your code is written entirely in Java?

Isn't it the same thing? When I add only the java tag, Android programmers do not see it, so I added it in Kotlin. If you want, you can also give the answer in Kotlin.

It's very different, the answers would vary quite substantially. Also, if you want Android programmers to see your question, you should tag your question with that tag. I just updated your question to reflect that.
